# How to transform a 3 variables Boolean Function into a K-map when some variables are not specified in the expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I looked at the already answered questions and used google, but I didn't found anything that explains the thing clearly. My problem is that I don't know how to solve function like

```
f(A,B,C)= (a+b)(a'+b'+c')(a+c)
```

Can someone please give me a path to follow in order to be able to solve them? thanks in advance !

Comment: You offer a specific "what if" function, but your question is actually quite general and there are not only whole shelves of books on the subject of general approaches, but frequent classes offered across the planet for the same thing. This isn't a good place for writing entire books -- though I may have been accused once or twice of doing so on occasion.

Comment: I'm not sure that i understood the meaning of your answer but thanks anyway :)

Comment: It was a suggestion to improve your question by narrowing it. It's far too broad, in my opinion, as it is. Unless I misread you.

Comment: I hope it's more clear now :)

Comment: I'd say that the new wording changes nothing about the scope. It is the same, so far as I can tell. Just slight differences in words. You should at the very least take some time to explain what you already know well and can apply and explain where you get stuck with your own example. At a minimum. But that's my opinion. Other ones are free to vary.

Comment: google `boolean logic  don't care`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework with no attempted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the same way you'd do sum of products, but with product of sums you target the zeros first.  For example, the first term tells you that if a and b are both low, the output will be low:

\begin{matrix}
bc & a  & 0& 1\\
00 &&  0\\
01 &&  0\\
10\\
11\\
\end{matrix}

The second term eliminates the case where abc = 111:

\begin{matrix}
bc & a  & 0& 1\\
00 &&  0\\
01 &&  0\\
10\\
11&&&0\\
\end{matrix}

Finally, the third term gives us zero when both a and c are low (redundantly including the abc = 000 condition)

\begin{matrix}
bc & a  & 0& 1\\
00 &&  0\\
01 &&  0\\
10&&0\\
11&&&0\\
\end{matrix}

Now backfill the ones and you're done.

\begin{matrix}
bc & a  & 0& 1\\
00 &&  0&1\\
01 &&  0&1\\
10&&0&1\\
11&&1&0\\
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 0):

You simply ignore the unused value.

So, if you have (a+b) you combine the a and b shapes

```
a
     a  0  1
b  0    0  1
   1    0  1

b
     a  0  1
b  0    0  0
   1    1  1

a+b
     a  0  1
b  0    0  1
   1    1  1
```

inserting c as rows will 'spread' the function over rows

```
     a  0  1
bc 00   0  1
   01   0  1
   11   1  1
   10   1  1
```

or, if ordered differently, you copy the rows and the shape when drawn on a plane gets split up.

```
     a  0  1
cb 00   0  1
   01   1  1
   11   1  1
   10   0  1
```

But since we have a grey code, the top and bottom and left and right edges join as though on a torus, so the shape is the same logically even if the projection to a plane breaks one of the shapes. With more than four variables (or more than two in one dimension) the shapes touch in places not in the plane so you need to get used to thinking beyond the plane shapes anyway.  You can have 000 001 011 010 110 111 101 100  but 000 is adjacent to 001, 010 and 100 but in the planar projection of the map a cell can only be adjacent to two cells in any one dimension.